# How does while input work?

Tags: c++, file-io

How does

```
while(cin >> variable)
```

actually work? Is it just a condition to loop until there is no input or does it get new input every time.

Comment: You should not change question completely invalidating all answers.

Comment: Actually i just made it more to the point its the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You at first read values of value1, value2, value3

```
inputFile >> value1;
 inputFile >> value2;
 inputFile >> value3;
```

and then overwrite them in the loop statement

```
while (inputFile >> value1 >> value2 >> value3){
```

The same is valid for read operations in the end of the loop

```
   inputFile >> value1;
    inputFile >> value2;
     inputFile >> value3;
 }
```

Remove these statements that are before the loop and in the end of the loop.

Also that to check whether three numbers form a valid tringle it is enough to check that each two numbers are greater than the third number.

Comment: @Aboogesnickle See my uodated post about how to check that three numbers form a balid triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work for `n/2` triangles, where `n` is the number of inputs you have. At the end of your loop, you read in the next three variables, but at the beginning of your loop (i.e., inside your `while(...)`), you read the *next* three variables, effectively skipping one set of input. Remove the `inputFile >> value1; inputFile >> value2; inputFile >> value3;` at the end of your `while`.

Comment: You do the same thing right before your `while` statement. You read in three values and promptly overwrite them. Get rid of those inputs as well.